# How to speed up rendering kdenlive Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, video, codecs, kdenlive

I am using kdenlive on my Ubuntu1 14.04. When i render videos, it is very slow. Takes as much time as the length of video.

I have Dell XPS L502X with Nvidia GeForce 540M. Is there anyway i can use my graphics card to speed up Rendering, like as CyberLink Power Director use nvidia card on Windows ? If there is any other alternative to kdenlive which renders Video fast, please suggest.

Comment: Seems no support for GPU encoding in ffmpeg https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Willagraphicscardmakex264encodefaster . Have you tried adding threads as CPU cores you have.

Comment: Yes,  now I checked after analysing. The messages from terminal. Yes it reduce time, but still I think using gpu performance can be improved.

Comment: Well, you'll have to wait as today, it doesn't exist...

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313, it seems some features have been implemented. check https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#NVENC & https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDACUVID . But it does not mean it will speed up instead you just give that job to GPU (but not both GPU+CPU)  . May be that when [OpenCL](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#OpenCL) gets ready

Comment: @user.dz thanks for the update :). Will wait for speedup ...